# Zend Framework bassed projects

Tags: zend-framework

Where can i see ZF-bssed project with nice architecture
DataMapper,Services, etc

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the apps

http://www.framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14134

http://devzone.zend.com/article/2060

Also, take a look at http://www.magentocommerce.com/

Comment: it not very good example - architecture in that projects is very bad

Comment: What's your reference when talking about nice architecture? Compared to what?